# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" for chrome.tab.query in background page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

I am using this code to get all opened tabs URL:

```
function setPhone(phone) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
    }, function (tabs) {
        var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
        console.log(tabURL);
    });
}
```

This is part of an extension that start listening a TCP socket. When a connection is established and a command is received, setPhone function is called. That function is called in an event:

```
function onAcceptCallback(tcpConnection, socketInfo) {
    var info = "[" + socketInfo.peerAddress + ":" + socketInfo.peerPort + "] Connection accepted!";
    log.output(info);
    console.log(socketInfo);
    tcpConnection.addDataReceivedListener(function (data) {
        var lines = data.split(/[\n\r]+/);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var line = lines[i];
            if (line.length > 0) {
                var info = "[" + socketInfo.peerAddress + ":" + socketInfo.peerPort + "] " + line;
                log.output(info);

                var cmd = line.split(/\s+/);
                try {
                    switch (cmd[0]) {
                        case 'Phone':
                            setPhone(cmd[1]);
                            tcpConnection.sendMessage('+OK-Phone');
                            break;
                        case 'SetClientPage':
                            clientEditPage = cmd[1];
                            tcpConnection.sendMessage('+OK-SetClientPage');
                            break;
                        case 'SetSearchPage':
                            clientSearchPage = cmd[1];
                            tcpConnection.sendMessage('+OK-SetSearchPage');
                            break;
                        default:
                            tcpConnection.sendMessage('+ERR-Comando No Encontrado');
                    }
                    //tcpConnection.sendMessage(Commands.run(cmd[0], cmd.slice(1)));
                } catch (ex) {
                    tcpConnection.sendMessage(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

and finally, this is the manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Busca Cliente Lipigas",
  "description": "Esta extension permite recibir un numero de telefono desde el servidor DDE y realizar la busqueda del cliente en la pagina Web de Lipigas.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "system.network"
  ],

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["tcp-server.js", "main.js"],
      "persistent": true
    }
  },

  "sockets": {
    "tcpServer": {
      "listen": "*"
    }
  }
}
```

All above produces error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

EDIT:

For testing, I have place the query method when the extension is started and the same error appears:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {

    chrome.tabs.query({
    }, function (tabs) {
        var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
        console.log(tabURL);
    });


    console.log('Aplicación iniciada.');
    startServer('127.0.0.1', 8888);
});
```

Any help please?
Cheers
Jaime

Comment: What do you mean by external? The link you gae did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing a chrome app, however `chrome.tabs.*` api can be only accessed by chrome extensions. That's why you got the error.

Comment: This is a chrome extension, as far as I know. And in fact, I install it using chrome extension manager. Why do you say this is a chrome app?

Comment: @jstuardo, see your manifest file, app and sockets are both chrome app terms.

Comment: But background pages are defined under app element and all tutorials that teach about creating chrome extensions, show that manifest file should have this structure. What I need to do is an extension that receives data from other application and does something with a tab according to the data received.

Comment: I don't believe you. There are no tutorials for extensions that use `app` key. See [*extensions* documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Comment: You are totally right. The fact is that I used a Chrome Extension template in Visual Studio, which added the "app" key to the manifest. But I have another problem now, Google Extensions does not allow sockets. Is it possible to communicate a Chrome Extension with an external Windows application?

Comment: @jstuardo, sure, [NativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is exactly what you want